# Can someone explain how does this code works

Tags: c#, arrays

We are doing currently **C# in Arrays**.And I have to get the **second largest number** from the **Input**. But i **dont know** **the function of this code**. Can someone explain this for me. **For the whole code** please have a view **[here](https://pastebin.com/Kuy51ZgL)**

**Code to explain:**

```
 static int ztgzahl(int[] ZL)
        {
            int MinZ = Int16.MinValue;
            int MaxZ = Int16.MinValue;
            for(int i = 0; i < ZL.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ZL[i] > MaxZ)
                {
                    MinZ = MaxZ;
                    MaxZ = ZL[i];
                }
                else if (ZL[i] > MinZ)
                {
                    MinZ = ZL[i];
                }
            }
            return MinZ;
        }
```

Comment: you might want to throw an exception if the array has less than two items. If `ZL` has less than `2` items, it will return `Int16.MinValue`, which is not technically correct (or another option is to explicitly state that behavior).

Comment: Also note that `int` (which is an alias for `Int32`) has a **much** larger range than `Int16`, so you should probably be using `int.MinValue` instead, since it's possible all the values are less than `Int16.MinValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code itterates over the array, trying to find the two highest numbers. However it uses completely messed up Variable names MinZ and MaxZ for that. It should be MaxA and MaxB or something like that.

And for each number it checks if the number is larger then the current MaxZ (the highest). If yes, it hands the previous second largest down to MinZ. If not it additionally checks if it just smaler then MinZ (as a number can be bigger the MaxZ, and still smaler then MinZ).

I am not 100% sure this works. Personally I would just sort the Arrays and get the 2nd from the right side. Or if this was a Database, get the 2nd from Bottom using a query. This kind of logic is notoriously prone for messing up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and yes the variable are not good! But it is for school purpose :)

Comment: The only way I see the logic not working as expected is if you pass in an array with less than 2 items in it. Otherwise what do you mean by *"This kind of logic is notoriously prone for messing up"*

Comment: @RufusL I am not 100% certain it will work. With nested If's, it is easy to miss one case. But I can not put my finger on any specific Problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Int16.MinValue
```

This will get the minimal value allowed for Int16

Then it iterates the *ZL* array, if it finds a value highest than the highest value found, it replaces the variable value, if not, it checks if it's place is possible as second highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my comments against the snippet below

```
static int ztgzahl(int[] ZL)
        {
            int MinZ = Int16.MinValue; // Min value of Int16 is -32768
            int MaxZ = Int16.MinValue; 
            for(int i = 0; i < ZL.Length; i++) //Iterating over each index of array
            {
                if (ZL[i] > MaxZ)    //If current element is greater than MaxZ
                {
                    MinZ = MaxZ;    //MinZ remainsthe same
                    MaxZ = ZL[i];   //MaxZ is the current element
                }
                else if (ZL[i] > MinZ) //If current element is greater than MinZ
                {
                    MinZ = ZL[i];      //MinZ is current element
                }
            }
            return MinZ;
        }
```

Based on the full snipet, there will not be any negative elements in the array. So considering a short array of 4 elements {3,1,5,7}

**1st Iteration:**

Both MinZ and MaxZ = -1

MinZ = -1

MaxZ = 3

**2nd Interation:**

MinZ = 1

**3rd Iteration:**

MinZ = 3

MaxZ = 5

**4th Iteration:**

MinZ = 5

MaxZ = 7

Therefore the second largest element is 5, which is returned by MinZ